# How to insert data from raspberer pi 3 flame sensor fire detect to MySQL database

Tags: python, mysql, raspberry-pi

I want to insert data from raspberry pi 3 to mysql database:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO import time import MySQLdb db =MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="123456", db="raspbd") cur = db.cursor()

GPIO SETUP

channel = 3 GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)GPIO.setup(channel, GPIO.IN)def callback(channel):print("flamedetected")GPIO.add_event_detect(channel,GPIO.BOTH, bouncetime=300) # let us know when the pin goes HIGH or LOW GPIO.add_event_callback(channel, callback) # assign function to GPIO PIN,Run function on change

infinite loop

while True:cur.execute("INSERT INTO flame (ID,flame,) VALUES (%s, %s)", [ID,flame])db.commit() db.rollback()time.sleep (1)cur.close()db.close()
```

Error message:

```
ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "flame.py", line 24, in cur.execute("INSERT INTO flame (ID,flame,) VALUES (%s, %s)", [ID,flame])
NameError: name 'ID' is not defined
```

Comment: ERROR:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "flame.py", line 24, in <module>
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO flame (ID,flame,) VALUES (%s, %s)", [ID,flame])
NameError: name 'ID' is not defined

Comment: It literally says whats wrong in the stacktrace

Comment: -1                                                                                                    for the unreadably broken code formatting.

Answer (score 0):

In my humble opinion you should avoid using an infinite loops, that's something you should avoid.

The error message says that the variable called ID has not been defined, meaning it doesn't exist, therefore has no value either. 
I assume that should be the ID in the MySQL DB table, which you better set it auto increment so you don't have to worry about it.

If that's the whole code you shared, you most likely will have many more error messages anyway. You need to read the data first from GPIO to be able to send it to the DB.

To directly answer how to get the data from the sensor to the database. I have no experience with GPIO at all. It is a well documented field of RPi.

First you need to read the data from the relevant pin/channel, then send it to the DB via an SQL query.

The GPIO wiki (https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/Inputs/) has a very thorough description how the reading can be done. I assume you were trying to do the threaded solution by attaching a callback function to the pin, which will be triggered every time the sensor sends a signal to the pin. I'm not sure if the correct way was this:

```
# ...after setting up the GPIO and the DB connection

flame = ""
def my_callback(channel):
    # ...do something here...
    flame = GPIO.input(channel)
    # or perhaps you want just a string when it happened
    # flame = "detected"

channel = 3        
GPIO.add_event_detect(channel, GPIO.RISING, callback=my_callback)

# then you should be able to write the value to the DB
cur.execute("INSERT INTO flame (ID,flame) VALUES (%s,%s)",[ID,flame])
# ...and continue with the DB job.

# please note that this piece of code is not complete
# and will not solve the error with the ID
```